# Odd things happen with JSP <c:choose> <c:when> <c:if>

Tags: jsp

A co-worker and I just came across a situation in JSP, and was wondering if Stack Overflow could help us understand what is going on.

We were having a logical issue with code looking like this:

```
<c:if test="test something">
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="test something else">
      <c:if test="yet again test"> //#1
        <c:set "set some stuff"/>
      </c:if>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise> //#2
      <c:if test="testing the else">
        <c:set "set for the else"/>
      </c:if>
    </c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>
</c:if>
```

What we were noticing was if the test at #1 failed we would never get into the otherwise statement (#2). We fixed this by combining the  (#1) with the test in the  above it.

Can someone explain to me why this happens? Does the inside  (#1) failing kick the logic out of the conditionals all together?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but your code is broken. `c:otherwise` is used inside a `c:choice` and not with a `c:if`

See code samples from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_choose_tag.htm)

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${salary <= 0}">
       Salary is very low to survive.
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${salary > 1000}">
        Salary is very good.
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        No comment sir...
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

and for if:

```
<c:if test="${salary > 2000}">
   <p>My salary is: <c:out value="${salary}"/><p>
</c:if>
```

Note that `c:if` does not have support for a `c:else` or `c:otherwise`

Comment: Thanks for the note. I have edited my post. That was a problem with me copying it over. It is not present in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

point at which your `<c:when test="test something else">` condition satifies, it's sibling `<c:otherwise>` , gets out of execution flow.

This is similar to below java if-else loop

```
c:when      ->    if(test something else){
                    //whatever code including your nested if->yet again test
c:otherwise ->    }else {
                     // otherwise code for testing the else
                  }
```

so it's a normal if-else in this case. when your `c:when` or `if` gets satisfied, `c:otherwise` or `else` is out of the execution flow